# How to check multiple attributes having unique combination within List where attribute names are available as separate collection. [C#]

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have the scenario where I have a List of selected attributes in string format.
Based on that list I want to perform an operation on actual object collection to check whether given properties having unique value combination within that list.

Example - Here Name and Type are the selected attributes (given in selectedProductAttributes list) we want to check uniqueness for this attributes with products collection. We might use reflection to retrieve actual properties but I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help appreciated.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

private List<string> selectedProductAttributes = new List<string> {"Name", "Type"};

private List<Product> products = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product {Name= "a", Type="t1", Price=10},
        new Product {Name= "a", Type="t1", Price=20},
        new Product {Name= "b", Type="t2", Price=30}
    };
```

Comment: Define `check whether given properties having unique value combination within that list?` what do you want to return a true or false if these combinations aren't unique ? i think you need to clarify your question a bit better and give us some intended output

Comment: Yes, I want to return True/False based on uniqueness.

Comment: How many properties are in product? also how many products, as reflection might be slow

Comment: There are limited properties maximum 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each property name that you want, you can use such function to check if the given property has unique values in the list:

```
bool IsUnique<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string propertyName)
{
    return list.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x))
        .GroupBy(x => x).All(x => x.Count() == 1);
}
```

*Example*

```
var properties = new List<string> { "Id", "Name" };
var isUnique = properties.All(p => IsUnique(list, p));
```

---

If for any reason, you are looking for a way to check of if the group of those fields is unique, like a composite key:

```
bool IsUnique<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, List<string> properties)
{
    var subData = list.Select(x => properties.Select(p => 
        x.GetType().GetProperty(p).GetValue(x)).ToList());
    var q = from d1 in subData
            from d2 in subData
            where d1.SequenceEqual(d2)
            select d1;
    return q.Count() == subData.Count();
}
```

*Example*

For example for the following list, the combination of "Id" and "Name" is not unique, because 1st and 3rd items in the list have the same combination of "Id" and "Name":

```
var list = new[] {
    new { Id= 1, Name="P1", Price = 100},
    new { Id= 2, Name="P2", Price = 200},
    new { Id= 1, Name="P1", Price = 300},
};
var properties = new List<string> { "Id", "Name" };
var isUnique = IsUnique(list, properties);  // ← returns false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but "PropertyName" is in the List and not a single string.

Comment: You can make both of the solutions faster if you are working on a huge list.

Comment: Reza with a new solution it won't work, as I am looking for the combination of property values to be unique

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, for example in above code sample, ("Id", "Name") combination should be unique in the list. I tried the solution and it's working properly.

Comment: Updated the example. You can simply try the result yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet and let me know if it is what you're after

```
var query = from product in products
        from property in typeof(Product).GetProperties()
        join toCompare in selectedProductAttributes on property.Name equals toCompare
        let temp = new {
            Name = property.Name,
            Value = property.GetValue(product)
        }
        group temp by temp.Name into gg
        select new
        {
            Name = gg.Key,
            IsDuplicated = gg.Count() > 1
        };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Martin this solution it won't work, as I am looking for the combination of property values to be unique.

Comment: Can you provide the output that you're expecting for the given dataset?

Comment: According to Product List, I mentioned output should be false as Name and Type combination value (i.e. a and t1) exists twice at position 0 and 1